# Link to image on Google drive from R Shiny app not working

Tags: r, shiny, google-drive-api

I want the app to desplay a company logo and import the image from my Google drive. However the link I get from Google does not display the image. The code works fine when importing the Shiny logo and also and example I found on Stack Overflow. See codes below:

This works fine:
h5("This app is developed with: ",
img(src = "https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/shiny.png", height = "30px"),"and R Studio"),

This link (src) to Google also is OK:
http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0By6SOdXnt-LFaDhpMlg3b3FiTEU

However, this link (src to my company logo image) does not work:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/14rF8ZSWL7Hzv2yTWdFCR1aOTw7-JrMKlqInMLEIDSM4/edit?usp=sharing

I have tried similar links to images stored in Dropbox and Microsoft OneDrive, but to no avail.

I do not get any error messages. The only result is the text I insert before the image and this icon:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTgZx.png)

Comment: its because the last link isnt a picture link, its a file

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! However, I don't see the difference. The images are uploaded to Google Drive as .png or .jpg files. And there is only one way to get a link: Rigth click the file and select 'Get a link'. So what am I doing wrong or missing here? Appreciate any further help :-)

Comment: your link should be like the first one, with black background, such as this:https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUotU.jpg?s=328&g=1, see on top its ending with `.jpg` or `jpeg` or `png`

Comment: Thanks again. I uploaded the image file to Google Images and got a link from there. It wotks fine. The idea is to have individual users' (companies) logos displayed on the app when the user logs on to it. Here is link to a demo version of the app with my company logo on the start-up page. Thanks again for your valuable help! https://tore47.shinyapps.io/R_MC_Risk_Demo_2_E/

Comment: Instead of using google docs, can you put all those images into the `www` folder where `server.R` is. You will need to create that folder if it doesnt exist

Comment: Again, thanks for useful tip. I have actually done that, but had some problems when publishing to shiny apps.io. Also, since I use MySQL to store data, I thought it more convenient to add or remove links to logos in the database in stead of re-publishing the app every time I need to add a logo. BR Tore

Answer (score 0):

The company logo image you are trying to retrieve is in fact a Google Document and not an image.

**What you can do:**

Upload the image as an actual image and not as a document and afterwards retrieve its link.

[image: file upload]

**OR**

Get the image from the document using either Apps Script or Docs API.

#### Reference

- [DocumentApp InlineImage Class Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/inline-image);
- [Docs API Documents:get](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get).

Answer (score 0):

you can use this alternative link for your projects "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=your_file_id" replace your file id that you will find in your url after /d "https://drive.google.com/file/d/**1aE5FZsOErES0xldkX-HFDfkshvd_R1Yc**/view?usp=drive_open"